# ActiveSync bootstrap initialization failed windows CE emulator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-ce, activesync

I am trying to run a visual studio 2008 project on a Windows CE emulator listed in visual studio. Receiving this error:

> Error 1   ActiveSync bootstrap initialization failed. Please
>   connect/cradle a real device or download the User-level Windows Mobile
>   Device Center Application from
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkid=67763   Device Connectivity
>   Component

I have checked online for solution but could not get very far. Is there a way to solve this for emulator?